# Can I mix cow & chicken manure?

Tags: vegetables, fertilizer, manure

Is there any disadvantage of mixing both? Will it add more value? I am planning to first dilute them in water and then apply in my veggie garden. I purchased these as bagged composted [chicken](http://prcompostco.com/poulet_poo.html) and [cow](http://prcompostco.com/bobs_best.html) manures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, mixing them is fine! I looked at the products you got, and they look composted well enough I think the best application method would be directly mixing into the top inches of the soil. I think that's better than diluting it in water, because it will stay in the soil better, and you won't lose as much nitrogen through evaporation/leaching. But in any case, it's composted, so most of the nitrogen is already stabilized until the organic matter breaks down further.

The chicken manure is going to be higher in nitrogen, and if it was raw, I wouldn't recommend it for direct application around some plants, but again, what you have is composted, and so is wide application.

Answer (score 1):

This is the biggest and best I have ever seen.

- 1 wheel barrow of soil
- 1 gallon of fresh chicken manure
- 1 gallon of fresh cow manure
- 1 cup of lime
- plenty of perlite

Do not put plants in this mix until they are 1 month old.

Answer (score -2):

There is no problem mixing both.  But if you are fertilizing vegetables, this is NOT a good choice of fertilizer!  Do you know how decomposed this manure IS?  Even if it were very decomposed it would have too much NITROGEN for vegetables unless you've got just leafy stuff like kale, lettuce, herbs.  If your vegetables need fertilizer, now, I'd use a good organic fertilizer with numbers similar to 4-6-5.  Less Nitrogen percentage compared to the Phosphorus and Potassium.  For the winter, these manures should be dumped on top of your garden soil. Soil organisms will feed on this SHIT, grins, IF it is decomposed...go back into the soil to poop it out, mixing this material into the soil FOR YOU.  If it isn't decomposed, the decomposers can use the high nitrogen to decompose this material down to be useable by the other soil organisms. In the spring turn your soil over before planting.  I'd also test my soil before planting.  Chicken and cow manure are great to incorporate Nitrogen and organic matter into one's soil but it is tough to know HOW much Nitrogen is being added.  There is one other thing to take note about and that is are the chickens and cows that donated this stuff on medications of ANY sort? Don't use it if so...only organically fed chickens/cows should be donating shit for vegetables.  Otherwise fine for ornamental plants.  Chemicals are chemicals.  Just because they are obviously 'organic' does not make them safe or correct to use without soil tests and KNOWING as much as you can about the chemical's origins.  Lots of weed seeds...weeds have NEVER bothered me but lots of weed seeds will make it through the digestive tracts.  Just so you know.  That would be another question.

Comment: Thanks Stormy for the reply. I purchased these manures from http://prcompostco.com/. Any feedback on these ?

Comment: Stormy, no. Manure is a great fertilizer for many plants. And composted manure can be used on almost anything. Believe me I've been doing it for some time (just like everyone else) and have awesome results.

Comment: So you are saying that this high nitrogen versus P and K is ok for vegetables, flowers?  Composted manure is great for soil improvement and adding chemicals necessary for healthy soil...could you see the percentages?

Comment: [this](http://www.onlinepot.org/grow/NPKCharts.htm) is a good chart. It shows the values for raw manures (which are actually far less strong than even some organic fertilizers). They are fairly well balanced, and if composted, are actually far lower in available npk value (although better for the soil in the long run)

Comment: All of these, manures, organic additives have Nitrogen that is higher in percentage than the P and K.  Any time one uses a fertilizer with this type of composition where N is higher will produce vegetative growth versus reproductive.  This year my hubby purchased a fertilizer that was FOR bloom, flowers, fruit but the percentage of N was still the highest and boy did that make a difference!!  I'll never do that again.  Lots 'n lots of weed seeds in manures.  Thanks for the reference.  I'm saving  this for sure...being less 'strong' isn't the problem.  The problem is simply percentages.

Comment: @stormy also, you have to remember that some of the chemicals in the manure have different compositions, and so the percentages are not directly what need to be even for proper balance. It's a lot more complicated than that. Also, plants don't need the same amounts of each one. Even if the chemicals were perfectly balanced relating to availability per mass, the plant wouldn't need equal amounts of each. And, the composition percentages in the manure/fertilizer will vary, depending on the chemical makeup of the individual components contributing to the total number. Anyway, that's part of it...

Comment: That's part of why I disagreed with your answer on here.